# getting lat/long coordinates from firebase/firestore collection

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-maps

im relative new to react native and firebase and it would be awesome if anyone could help me with this problem. currently when im adding new posts to my firebase collection i display all post with a flatlist and it works fine. but is it possible to get only the currentLatitude and currentLongitude for my markers? my target is to generate a new marker for each post.

```js
Events = []


this.firestore.collection("Events").get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    Events.push(doc.data())
  })
})


    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <MapView 
                        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
                        mapType='hybrid'   
                        showsUserLocation style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={{latitude: //currentLatitude,                         
                        longitude: //currntLongitude}}
                        title={("Test")}
                        description={("Test")} 
                    />               
                    </MapView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do u mean of "is it possible to get only the currentLatitude and currentLongitude for my markers? " And what is final result should be in your app?

Comment: thanks for replying @DevAS! I need to get the lat and long coordinates from my Firestore doc to put them into the marker component. and the final result should be a marker for each doc/post which is stored in my Firestore.. like airbnb for example.

Comment: So where's the problem? As i see in the last image you get lat and long and u pass it to marker! What you see on the map should be the location marker

Comment: If you have some gif or image to the final result that will help to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

@DevAS thanks for your patience.. this was made from 3 different .js files.. but I don't now how to get it just into the map.js.

The final result should look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAZle.jpg)

Everything except for the lat/lng cords are supposed to be in the callout-window.

Item.js:

```js
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Fire from '../screens/Fire'


const profileImageSize = 36;
const padding = 12;

export default class Item extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
        });


    if (!this.props.imageWidth) {
      // Get the size of the web image
      Image.getSize(this.props.image, (width, height) => {
        this.setState({ width, height });
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { title, address, name, imageWidth, imageHeight, image, currentLatitude, currentLongitude } = this.props;

    // Reduce the name to something
    const imgW = imageWidth || this.state.width;
    const imgH = imageHeight || this.state.height;
    const aspect = imgW / imgH || 1;

    return (
      <View>
        <Header image={{ uri: this.state.user.avatar }} name={this.state.user.name} />
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#D8D8D8",
            width: "100%",
            aspectRatio: aspect
          }}
          source={{ uri: image }}
        />
        <Metadata 
        name={this.state.user.name} 
        address={address}
        title={title}
        currentLongitude={currentLongitude}
        currentLatitude={currentLatitude}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Metadata = ({ name, address, title, currentLongitude, currentLatitude}) => (
  <View style={styles.padding}>
    <IconBar />
    <Text style={styles.text}>{name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{address}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{title}</Text>  
    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Lat: {currentLatitude}</Text> 
    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Lng: {currentLongitude}</Text> 
  </View>
);

const Header = ({ name, image }) => (
  <View style={[styles.row, styles.padding]}>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <Image style={styles.avatar} source={image} />
      <Text style={styles.text}>{name}</Text>
    </View>
    <Icon name="ios-more" />
  </View>
);

const Icon = ({ name }) => (
  <Ionicons style={{ marginRight: 8 }} name={name} size={26} color="black" />
);

const IconBar = () => (
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <Icon name="ios-heart-empty" />
      <Icon name="ios-chatbubbles" />
      <Icon name="ios-send"/>
    </View>
    <Icon name="ios-bookmark" />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: { fontWeight: "600" },
  subtitle: {
    opacity: 0.8
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  padding: {
    padding
  },
  avatar: {
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#D8D8D8",
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: "#979797",
    borderRadius: profileImageSize / 2,
    width: profileImageSize,
    height: profileImageSize,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    marginRight: padding
  }
});
```

List.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

import Footer from './Footer';
import Item from './Item';

class List extends React.Component {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item {...item} />;
  keyExtractor = item => item.key;
  render() {
    const { onPressFooter, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        ListFooterComponent={footerProps => (
          <Footer {...footerProps} onPress={onPressFooter} />
        )}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default List;
```

FeedScreen.js

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { LayoutAnimation, RefreshControl } from "react-native";

import List from "../components/List";
import Fire from "./Fire";

// Set the default number of images to load for each pagination.
const PAGE_SIZE = 5;
console.disableYellowBox = true;
export default class FeedScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    data: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Check if we are signed in...
    if (Fire.shared.uid) {
      // If we are, then we can get the first 5 posts
      this.makeRemoteRequest();
    } else {
      // If we aren't then we should just start observing changes. This will be called when the user signs in
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.makeRemoteRequest();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Append the item to our states `data` prop
  addPosts = posts => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      let data = {
        ...previousState.data,
        ...posts
      };
      return {
        data,
        // Sort the data by timestamp
        posts: Object.values(data).sort((a, b) => a.timestamp < b.timestamp)
      };
    });
  };

  // Call our database and ask for a subset of the user posts
  makeRemoteRequest = async lastKey => {
    // If we are currently getting posts, then bail out..
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // The data prop will be an array of posts, the cursor will be used for pagination.
    const { data, cursor } = await Fire.shared.getPaged({
      size: PAGE_SIZE,
      start: lastKey
    });

    this.lastKnownKey = cursor;
    // Iteratively add posts
    let posts = {};
    for (let child of data) {
      posts[child.key] = child;
    }
    this.addPosts(posts);

    // Finish loading, this will stop the refreshing animation.
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };

  // Because we want to get the most recent items, don't pass the cursor back.
  // This will make the data base pull the most recent items.
  _onRefresh = () => this.makeRemoteRequest();

  // If we press the "Load More..." footer then get the next page of posts
  onPressFooter = () => this.makeRemoteRequest(this.lastKnownKey);

  render() {
    // Let's make everything purrty by calling this method which animates layout changes.
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    return (
      <List
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.loading}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
          />
        }
        onPressFooter={this.onPressFooter}
        data={this.state.posts}
      />
    );
  }
}
```